# How can I delete fonts from my code, under Windows?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, fonts, installation

[This article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/apr08/hey0425.mspx) showed me how to install fonts from a script, but now I'm faced with the problem of removing them. How can I do that ? Any language is ok, I'll convert the info to what I need later.

EDIT: Okay, so I now know how to uninstall fonts ( most of the part at least ). I'm issuing calls to `RemoveFontResource`. After that I use `SendMessage` with parameters: `0xffff,0x001D,0,0` ( HWND_BROACAST,WM_FONTCHANGE ... and I forgot what the other two parameters stand for ). The thing is, this deletes the font, but in the `Control Panel`'s `Fonts` entry, the font still appears there ( even though if you try to delete it from there as well, it will say it cannot read from source file or disk.

So basically, I'm deleting a font in this order:

- deleting physically from the `C:\Windows\Fonts`
- calling RemoveFontResource
- calling SendMessage

What's the proper way of uninstalling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From all the documentation I've ever seen those three lines of code are the "proper" way to do it but as we well know it doesn't quite work - as expected.

```
RemoveFontResource(fontPath);               
DeleteFile(fontPath);
::SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

**REBOOT**

I executed the code above and duplicated your problem (control panel still shows the font, however the font file is gone).  I then rebooted.  Now the font is gone from the Fonts Control Panel applet.

Something else to note: even though control panel still showed the font as "there" applications no longer listed it in their font lists (I specifically tried Wordpad, before and after deleting webdings.ttf - without rebooting)

Yea i know - rebooting is a poor solution - especially if you need to update the Font since you can't reinstall it (via the control panel anyways - it claims the font is still installed) until you reboot after removing it (I tried).

However if all you want to do is remove the font - its not the worst solution - the font is *essentially* gone after you uninstall it (apps don't see it, its only visible in control panel fonts as far as i can tell) and you wouldn't need to force a reboot.

From the SDK help on [RemoveFontResourceFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162922(VS.85).aspx) (which may indicate why the oddness is seen)

> If there are outstanding references to
>   a font, the associated resource
>   remains loaded until no device context
>   is using it.

Comment: Yeah, but this should be done by an automated process. Rebooting kind of isn't an option.

Comment: So a little further investigation seems to point to the WMI service. If you restart that service *after* the font is deleted the control panel font  list is correct (NOTE: if you have c:\windows\fonts folder open in explorer when you do  the restart WMI service and just press F5 it *still* shows it, but exit and restart the fonts control applet and you'll see its gone AND you can re-install the font) all without a reboot...  Further Note: I tried deleting the font when the WMI service wasn't running and it wasn't until it was started again that deleted font was removed from the control panel.

Comment: Can you also list the command to restart the WMI service? Can it be done from the command line?

Comment: You can use the net command to this from a command line.  You can find the service name on the service properties page in the services control panel app for the the specific service.  For WMI:  `net stop wmiapsrv`  to stop it, `net start wmiapsrv` to start it (AFAIK there isn't a restart command)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This really helped.

Answer (score 4):

Once you find the actual filename as Havenard mentioned and using the article you mentioned you can do a

```
objFSO.DeleteFile(FontFilePath);
```

where FontFilePath is the file path of the file you want to delete.

More Info here: 
[technet article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/jan06/hey0126.mspx)

A problem that you may run into, which I didn't think of until I saw your comment, is that a program may require that font for some particular item. All known system fonts are stored within the registry. If you remove a font, you should also remove the key from the registry. Registry paths are as follows

```
Windows 95
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Fonts]

Windows NT
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
```

The keys are as followed:

```
Key name = Full name of the font
Key type = REG_SZ
Key Value = name of font file
```

Comment: I could just use a delete call. I was wondering if other steps would be involved ( like the registry ).

Answer (score 1):

All your fonts can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\

Explorer will mask this folder to display the font names instead of the real file names, but its all there. You can edit and comment out the lines of C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\desktop.ini to disable this feature and reveal the font files (maybe you need to reopen the Explorer to take effect).